# How to click on a in-line tab with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm on a webpage with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/.../chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')
link = 'http://performance.morningstar.com/funds/etf/total-returns.action?t=IWF'
driver.get(link)
```

How do I click on this tab called "Monthly":

[image]

**EDIT**:

The HTML that corresponds to this section is:

[image]

In this case, what "element" should I select to click on?

Comment: element = driver.find_element('XX')
element.click() ?

Comment: Yes I was asking exactly what "element" I should be looking for...

Comment: then you should view the html and find the tab exactly

Comment: I guess the real problem is I don't really know html syntax

Comment: um shouldn't you just click on the `<a tabname="#tabmonth" onclick="onTrailingReturnsClick('m', '#tab-month-end-content','','en-US');" class="">Monthly</a>`

Comment: yeah you should really learn some html basics if you want to be able to use any of this sort of thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in this way:

```
elem1= driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='in_tabs']")
elem1.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@tabname='#tabmonth']").click()
```

As you can imagine, with the first you select the element **in_tabs** and with the second the interested element.